# Sum column only from the last hour where 2 id's equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables which I need to compare it's id's and sum only the rows that have similar id.
As a result i need to show date, id, sum(for each id)

My current code is

```
Select a.OraReg,
       a.IdMezzo ,
       b.OraReg, 
       b.IdMezzo, 
       SUM(Saliti) over() as totalCount
from FLASH_STORICO.dbo.D_MSG_CONTAPASS as a
  inner join FLASH_STORICO.dbo.D_MSG_BORDO as b 
     on a.IdMezzo =b.IdMezzo 
    and a.OraReg = b.OraReg 
where a.OraReg > DATEADD(hour, -1, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
order by a.IdMezzo
```

My current result show same sum for every id,

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: You will get more anwsers when you show sample data and the required result

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and also easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: For sure one of the problems is that you're missing `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample? It will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
   SELECT a.OraReg
    ,a.IdMezzo
    ,SUM(Saliti) AS SumOfSaliti
FROM FLASH_STORICO.dbo.D_MSG_CONTAPASS a
INNER JOIN FLASH_STORICO.dbo.D_MSG_BORDO b ON a.IdMezzo = b.IdMezzo
    AND a.OraReg = b.OraReg
WHERE
    AND a.OraReg > DATEADD(hour, - 1, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
GROUP BY a.OraReg
    ,a.IdMezzo
ORDER BY a.IdMezzo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT a.OraReg ,a.IdMezzo  ,b.OraReg   ,b.IdMezzo  ,SUM(Saliti) AS totalCount
FROM FLASH_STORICO.dbo.D_MSG_CONTAPASS AS a
JOIN FLASH_STORICO.dbo.D_MSG_BORDO AS b ON a.IdMezzo = b.IdMezzo AND a.OraReg = b.OraReg
WHERE a.OraReg > DATEADD(hour, - 1, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
GROUP BY a.OraReg,a.IdMezzo,b.OraReg,b.IdMezzo
ORDER BY a.IdMezzo
```

And if this not works then follow @GuidoG suggestion.